# how can I make an undecorated window containing a button with java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I've created a round window with java , It's undecorated ..the problem is when I tried to add a button or a label in the frame ,nothing is shown inside.

could someone Please help me ?

*edited*

this is the code I made :

```
 public class main {

static public JPanel p;
 public static JLabel label1 ;
 public static JLabel label2 ;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    label1 = new JLabel("Name : ");
    label2= new JLabel("surname : ");
    p=new JPanel();
    p.add(label1);
    p.add(label2);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(p);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setShape(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200));
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setContentPane(p);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: post some relevant code for better understanding

Comment: It's probable that the button has been positioned outside the bounds of the visible area

Comment: @pietà Now it's clear that MadProgrammer was right, the `FlowLayout` of `p` still behaves "normally", and chooses the position according to the size of `p`, not the shape of `frame`. Technically, the size of `frame` is still a 500x500 rectangle, but only the Oval (where `x` & `y` = `200`) is being drawn. (The first label is approximately at `x = 225` and `y = 10`)

Comment: @LuxxMiner thanks for your response ..
I'm confused , I've tested many positions of the  `p` but it  still not visible in the shape of frame ..
does `frame.setUndecorated(true);` have any influence on the visibility of labels in the shape of frame ?